# Python: Reading and obtaining certain parts of a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file that has coordinates in a format of `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`. How would I be able to obtain just the `y1` and `y2` coordinates?

Example:

```
[23, 45, 90, 79]
```

Obtain `45` and `79`

Comment: Text file or list? Add more context pls..

Comment: What have you tried ? Read the file, split and select the good part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
import re

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        x, y = re.findall(r'\d+.*?(\d+).*?\d+.*?(\d+)', line)[0] 
        print(x,y)
```

Comment: Thanks this was perfect

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [23, 45, 90, 79]
```

`x[1]` will be `45` and `x[3]` will be 79.
So you can print them as `print(x[1],x[3])`.The output will be `45 79`

```
x = [[23, 45, 90, 79],[191, 64, 243, 93],[437, 76, 514, 127]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    print(x[i][1],x[i][3])
```

will print:

```
45 79
64 93
76 127
```

Comment: `x = [[23, 45, 90, 79],[191, 64, 243, 93],[437, 76, 514, 127]]` `print(x[0][1])` will print 45

Answer (score 0):

If the coordinates always remain at the same position you could use:

```
array = [23,45,90,79]
y1_y2 = [array[1], array[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a string like `s` in the given code, Use the strip functions to remove `[`,`]` and use the split function, otherwise convert the list, `s = [23, 45, 90, 79]` into an string by `s = str(s)`:

```
s = '[23, 45, 90, 79]'
s = s.strip('[').strip(']').split(',')
#Now getting y1 and y2 :
y1 = int(s[1])                # You can use the float() function if needed
y2 = int(s[3])
```